# typeError: _ firebase_index_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_17__.DEFUALT.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have been receiving this error `typeerror: _ firebase_index_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_17__.DEFUALT.collection is not a function`, and cannot figure out where it is coming from... I have firebase installed and am calling it in my file, but still receive this error... any ideas?

Comment: How are you importing the firebase libraries in your file?

Comment: like this: `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` also,
`import 'firebase/firestore';`

Comment: Could you add that to your original post?

Answer (score 0):

From the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup):

> Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first.

So, try and replace:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
```

with

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Comment: @Pheonix it didn’t work unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Gianluca could you add the code in which you're calling the function and importing the libraries to your original post?